# Why does CodeIgniter redirect not remove the hash/pound (#) at the end of the URL?

Tags: codeigniter

I am not sure if this is really a CodeIgniter issue or a browser issue. This happens in Chrome, but not Safari. However, I would assume it should not be happening in any browser.

If you go to **example.com/foo#** that contains

```
redirect('bar');
```

you would expect to end up at **example.com/bar**. Instead, you end up at **example.com/bar#**. I don't understand why the hash does not go away. It makes no sense. What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it can't. **The hash tag is only accessible by a client side script**. Code Igniter, PHP or any other server side script won't even know what is after the # sign. The request sent to the server is that before the # sign. The part after #sign is passed to the document to interpret. If there is an element with the id as the # sign, the page scrolls down to it. Otherwise js can read it and do things with it as you desire.

Also, an HTTP redirect transfers the request with the same parameters as the original page, so  the hastag is also passed on

Answer (score 12):

Use the refresh method if you need to drop the hash:

```php
redirect('bar', 'refresh');
```

Comment: This answers the question, and not just that: in the specific scenario of an installed (add to homescreen) web app on iOS, redirects fail completely without the 'refresh' option. This answer solved 2 of my problems, thanks.